# Creating an array in rails3 that displays the difference between two records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So lets say my model is updated every day with new records (thanks to a cron job), and each record has field that is a regular integer. The integer is never smaller than the day before.

Currently my array is created by:

```
where(:user_id => user.id).where("date(created_at) = ?", date).select(:mynumber)
```

this grabs all of the records belonging to a user, based on a date variable I've defined, and grabs the my number field to put into the array.

What I would like in the array, is the difference between the date's mynumber field, the day before date's mynumber field.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

-Elliot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you need to do versioned models (i.e. keeping track of previous attributes). Try:

https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions